# D3: mouseover text changes within an area in sunburst

Tags: d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I have a sunburst code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/EG0MzWEPB242g7VdSQQd?p=preview

When I click the orange area that corresponds to "from tumor cell" (see the caption below in the diagram), I get focussed diagram centered on "from tumor cells".

When I mouseover the area in the region marked "Liver or Pancreas", the texts in the caption box below changes while it should not. I suppose this problem is only in the second and third quadrant (90 degree to 270 degree). I couldn't find a way to solve this problem after spending so much time.

I hope some one has an answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're attaching the mouse over handlers to the `g` element, which isn't updated when you click on a segment. The easy way to fix this is to attach the handlers to the `path` elements, which do get updated, instead. In that case you probably also want to set the `text` elements to receive no pointer events so that there are no spurious mouse events when moving over them.

Complete demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eMDDZj1dxQHBalAzoyI6?p=preview).

Comment: I see the cause of the problem now. Thanks